# Blocked users still show in chat sidebar

Tags: bug, chat

I blocked all messages from a user in chat but I can still see them in the sidebar. This feels like a bug?

To clarify, I selected `ignore this user (everywhere)`

Messages can be seen in the sidebar:
[image]

But are missing (as they should be) from actual chat:
[image]

Comment: This definitely is a bug. Although I'm not sure how much effort the Powers That Be are willing to invest into fixing it. Chat has never really been a breadwinner, so it'd probably be quite low on their list of priorities.

Comment: meaning this will take more than 8 weeks ?

Comment: @Pac0 Meaning that it'll take more than 2 years, if you're lucky.

Comment: @Pac0 in Valve time. I needed to get that clarified.

Comment: The best solution to any problem is to stop visiting Lounge<C++>

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem isn't present just right after ignoring a user? I've got a big fat ignore list, and I never see these users in the sidebar, even when I check the transcripts and make sure that they posted the newest message in another room. A few days ago I added a user to my ignore list, and at that moment their pre-existing message in the sidebar didn't go away, but I haven't seen their messages since. So I suspect that this is an intermittent effect right after ignoring a user, and a refresh might fix it on the spot.

Comment: Correction: the problem exists in freshly loaded chatrooms. If there have already been messages loaded in the sidebar, I don't see ignored users there. If I reload the page when an ignored user posted the last message to another room, their message appears after reload.